React Native App Restarts After Granting Motion & Fitness Permission on iOS
I'm developing a React Native application that requires Motion & Fitness permissions for optimal functionality.
Issue: When a user initially denies the permission request and subsequently grants it through the device settings, the app unexpectedly restarts. This behavior is observed specifically for Motion & Fitness permissions, but not for Location permissions.
Current Implementation:

I'm using react-native-permissions to handle permission checks and requests.
If the user taps "Don't Allow," I guide them to the device settings screen to enable the necessary permissions.

Expected Behavior:
After granting permissions in settings, the app should resume its current state without restarting.

It is expected that the app restarts. Since there is no way for an app to get a notification that the permission has changed, changing permissions in settings typically restarts the app.  The same thing happens for other permissions such as Bluetooth. Whenever your app is not onscreen it should be prepared to be terminated
